# Hibernate - sessionFactory returns a session that is closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can I deal with a situation where

`session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

returns a closed session to me (to my app-level code)?

Here sessionFactory is of type `org.hibernate.SessionFactory`

Should I do something check like `if (!session.isOpen())`...
But then if this check returns true... what should I do?

Comment: Do you make use of `@Transactional` ? What are you trying to do ? Can you post code?

Comment: There is far too little information here to give any sort of reasonable answer. Please expand the question and give an example of what you are trying to accomplish along with some code.

Comment: Is the ```sessionFactory``` from ```EntityManagerFactory``` correct?